# how to use xpathexpression to get the <tr style="">

Tags: java, xpath

With such a dom tree:

```
<tr></tr>
<tr style=""></tr>
<tr width=""></tr>
```

How can I use xpath to get the tag tr with the attr style?  
I have tried the xpathexpression of `//tr[@style]` but it returns 0 trs.  
If I use `//tr[@*]` it returns 2 trs.  
What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `//tr[@style='']`, @style selects value of the attribute and since it is empty it is treated as false.

Comment: actually the tr is like this:  <tr style="style1"></tr>  and i use the xpathexpression //tr[@style="style1"] then it doesnt work.

Comment: Are you using XPather or something to test your XPath? //tr[@style='style'] or //tr[@style='style']/text() should give you something -- if it really corresponds with your HTML.

Comment: i have found out the reason.The style="width:19px;bgcolor:white" attr is changed to width:19px bgcolor:white ....so when i use the //tr[@width='19px'] i can get what i want.